# How to sign out from Facebook on a lost iPod

Tags: facebook

My iPod was stolen. I changed my Facebook password and it still says 2 devices are connected. How can I remotely logout of Facebook on the lost iPod?

Comment: Could you rephrase your question so that it is actually a _question_? It is a bit hard to read what you really want to accomplish.

Comment: It could be that you are logged in another session other than the one on the iPod. Check Punchlinern's answer.

Answer (score 16):

I assume you want to end the Facebook session (log out) on the iPod? To do that, follow these steps:

Enter settings
[image: FB Settings]

Go to the `Security` tab and click the `Where You're Logged In` section
[image: Security tab]

Here you'll find all logged in sessions. You can choose to `End activity` on all those associated with the iPod. In the below picture you see those associated with my Android device as an example. Look for iPod or iOS instead.
[image]

It can also be a good idea to remove it from the trusted browsers, still in the `Security` tab in settings:
[image]

Comment: Just one comment... your red arrows should be HAND DRAWN. ;)

Comment: Haha, I like to use the so powerful features of MS Paint.

Answer (score 3):

Simply go to security tab in Facebook settings.
There is an option to remove devices

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to login to your account with a wrong password or click on forgot your password option from any other device. Facebook will ask for your phone or email id to send you the code or password reset link. click that link and then facebook will ask for your new password and an option at the bottom to log you out of other devices. check that option and enter a new password. you will be logged out of all the other devices.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to removing the device from your Facebook account as @Punchlinern suggested, I would recommend [erasing your device](http://support.apple.com/kb/ph2701) from Apple's web site. That would take care of other files, accounts, etc.